# python function string parameter convert to variable name

Tags: python, string, function, variables

I'm rather new to Python and programming in general, so I apologise in advance if my terminology is incorrect.

```
hue_alert_delay = 0

def delays(name, delay):
    global hue_alert_delay

    if name == 'hue_alert_delay':
        for i in range(0, delay):
            hue_alert_delay += 1
            time.sleep(1)

        hue_alert_delay = 0

delays('hue_alert_delay', 60)
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

I would like the function to convert the 'name' parameter, which is a string input, into a pre-exiting variable, which will negate the need for multiple IF statements.

The above example includes only one IF statement, but for my project there will be a lot more and I would rather keep the function clean and simple.

This won't work, but it's what I'm trying to aim for:

```
hue_alert_delay = 0

def delays(name, delay):
    global name

    for i in range(0, delay):
        name += 1
        time.sleep(1)

    hue_alert_delay = 0

delays('hue_alert_delay', 60)
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary like so.

```
vars = {'hue_alert_delay':0}
def delays(name, delay):
  for i in range(0, delay):
      vars[name] += 1
      time.sleep(1)
  vars[name] = 0
```

You can also use `globals()[name]` but I won't recommend it.

Comment: The `global` keyword is unnecessary here. You're not trying to reassign to that name at any point. You're just mutating that object.

Comment: Thank you very very much, I applied this principle to my project and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I'm rather new to forums too :). Should I update the post some how to explain that it's resolved?

Comment: @Sparkacus No, you should click on the tick and mark this as the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dict:

```
values = {
    'hue_alert_delay': 0
}

def delays(name, delay):
    values[name] += 1
```

Whenever you feel like using "variable variables", what you most likely really want is a dict storing key-value associations. Yes, there *are* other ways to do literally what you want, but that soon leads to insane code.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary:

```
vars = {'hue_alert_delay':0}

def delays(name, delay):
    for i in range(delay):
        vars[name] += 1
        time.sleep(1)

    vars[name] = 0

delays('hue_alert_delay', 60)
```